# Is there a way to make Spring reload bootstrap properties dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-commons-config, netflix-archaius

I have a spring-boot app that autoconfigures an instance of Netflix's DynamicPropertyFactory. This enables us to read any properties spring is aware of plus any additional sources we specify.

The issue arises when we change a spring property that is used in core spring classes. For example `logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO` is used on core classes or spring before, during, and after applicationContext setup. If we change this property while the application is running to say `logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE`...

dynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getStringProperty() eventually realizes the change. However, the spring core classes continue to log at INFO rather than change to TRACE as expected.